# Duplicating records for a date range

Tags: sql, performance, teradata, ansi-sql

I have to duplicate records from week level data and push it back so that it fills in the previous week with the data.  So i get a row for 1/6 which is a Saturday, and then fill in all the columns to have the same data except the date until 1/1 (Sunday).

So my source is
date, info
1/6, a

target should be
1/7, b |
1/6, a |
1/5, a |
1/4, a | 
1/3, a |
1/2, a |
1/1, a

** sorry for the format, couldn't get it to display correctly.

So far the best ways i have thought to do this are either by using several union alls

```
SELECT date, info FROM test
 UNION ALL
SELECT date - 1, info FROM test
 UNION ALL
SELECT date - 2, info FROM test
```

ect.

or to do a controlled Cartesian join

```
SELECT tmp_date AS date, info FROM test AS test
INNER JOIN date_temp_table AS dt
  ON dt.tmp_date <= test.date
    AND dt.tmp_date > test.date - 7
```

Now Both of the above methods work however they are both terribly inefficient and nearly kill my database (Teradata)  So im open to any ideas as to how to improve this.

Comment: Since `date` is a reserved word, I'm guessing this is only an example, correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you actually want, but in TD13.10 it's easy to replicate rows based on periods using EXPAND ON:

```
SELECT 
   BEGIN(pd) AS dt,
   info
FROM test 
EXPAND ON PERIOD(datecol-7, datecol) AS pd
```

Dieter